# php page can not load completely

Tags: nginx, php

My web page can not load completely.
Input the command and reload the special page

```
tail -f /var/log/php-fpm/error.log
```

then got the error:

```
[26-Aug-2014 14:12:58] WARNING: [pool www] child 5622 exited on signal 11 (SIGSEGV) after 14.420797 seconds from start
[26-Aug-2014 14:12:58] NOTICE: [pool www] child 5635 started
```

At the same time the nginx error log is:

```
2014/08/26 14:12:58 [error] 5550#0: *4 readv() failed (104: Connection reset by peer) while reading upstream, client: 106.xxx.xxx.xxx, server: 115.xx.xxx.xxx, request: "GET /xxx/xxx/xxx.html HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://127.0.0.1:9000", host: "115.xx.xxx.xxx"
```

Can anyone help me? Thank you sincerely!

Comment: Fix your PHP script.

Comment: place `echo` messages in the code and check till where is it loading...then debug the code for which `echo` is not done...i doubt this has to do with code rather than server!

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem though nginx was not showing any error (s). I fixed it by changing buffering on nginx. Put the following:

```
fastcgi_max_temp_file_size 0;

fastcgi_buffer_size 4K;
fastcgi_buffers 64 4k;
```

in your nginx `location` block.

You'll end up with something like:

```
location ~ \.php$ {
    try_files $uri /index.php =404;
    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
    fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
    fastcgi_index index.php;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    fastcgi_max_temp_file_size 0;
    fastcgi_buffer_size 4K;
    fastcgi_buffers 64 4k;
    include fastcgi_params;
}
```

For details check https://www.namhuy.net/3120/fix-nginx-upstream-response-buffered-temporary-file-error.html